# DLL property Copy to local

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

IN my C# project i have a "UILanguage Dll" which is located in separate folder in Binary location,  The path for dll is probed in EXE.Config file of referenced application.

How to prevent a "DLL" from being set its "Copy Local"  Property to True when it is referenced  in other projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to doing this kind of stuff is to regiter the Dll into GAC.

There are two way in which u can place the assembly into GAC.

Using the utility gacutil -i Here you should give the complete path of the dll

> c:>gactutil -i c:\foldername\assemblyname\bin\assemblyname.dll

The second method is u can drag the .dll file from the bin folder of the assembly and drop it into the folder C:\winnt\Assembly

Here you can see the Registering the Assembliy into GAC

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, go to the project that references "UILanguage Dll", locate *References* folder and the "UILanguage Dll" in there, right click on it, select

*Properties > CopyLocal = False*